# RDL report - Row Group without a Group expression

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I'm working on converting an RDL report to an RDLC. The RDL contains a row group. However, the row group doesn't appear to actually be grouping on a field.

As seen here, a group expression doesn't appear to be specified.
[image: Row group with no group expression]

However, in the Sorting tab, there's a "Sort by" specification, shown here.
[image: Row group's Sort by expression]

Looking at the XML in the RDL file, here's the row group:

```
    <TablixMember>
      <Group Name="table8_Details_Group">
        <DataElementName>Detail</DataElementName>
      </Group>
      <SortExpressions>
        <SortExpression>
          <Value>=Fields!Dated.Value</Value>
        </SortExpression>
      </SortExpressions>
      <TablixMembers>
        <TablixMember />
      </TablixMembers>
      <DataElementName>Detail_Collection</DataElementName>
      <DataElementOutput>Output</DataElementOutput>
      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
    </TablixMember>
```

**So, my question is:** Why would a row group be added to a report, which doesn't group rows on a field? It *appears* that the only purpose of this row group is to sort rows based off of the "Dated" field. Am I missing something? It strikes me as odd that a "row group" would be added to a report, which doesn't group any rows, and only sorts them.

Comment: I think initially who added the group wanted to group by `Dated` then for testing purposes deleted the group expression. It is unlikely add a group just for sorting even more knowing you can sort your data in multiple ways.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Interesting, ok. I'll check with the original developer and see if that was what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. Even the detail row of a report tablix has a group associated with it. It just doesn't group anything. If you change that, the display of the details will be affected, and probably not in the way you want, either.

The sort setting is just that, it tells the report how to sort the detail rows. There is nothing wrong here.

Comment: This looks like it was the problem - I was looking at a detail row rather than a row group.